# How to determine odds in a game similar to roulette

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-distribution

A game similar to Roulette has 360 slots.
20 of these slots are 'scoring' positions.
Each slot will only accomodate 1 ball.

If a number of balls are introduced (Say 3)

What are the chances that any 1 of these 3 balls will settle into a scoring slot
What are the chances that any 2 of these 3 balls will settle into scoring slots
What are the chances that all 3 of these 3 balls will settle into scoring slots

I am hoping somebody might take the time to demonstrate the equation used to determine the above and perhaps
also give a brief explaination and use the statistical phraseology which might describe the mathematics.

Many thanks

Comment: If this homework, you should probably add the [tag:self-study] tag in order to get better guidance.

Comment: No this is not homework - this is a real world archaeology question which I have presented in the format of a game for simplification. If it were homework, I likely would have been given some idea of how to approach this, but I have no mathematical or statistical skills beyond defining the question.

Comment: Does "any 1 of these" mean "only one of these"? i.e. an arbitrary ball scores, others not.

Comment: Any ball in a scoring slot is a score. One ball per slot. What is the chance of achieving a single score when all balls are in play. What are the chances of achieving multiple scores when all balls are in play

Comment: Do you want to share something closer to the actual archelogy question, just to make sure your 'game' has _exactly_ the same probability structure?

Comment: I second BruceET's request. It is almost never good to leave out the background of the question. (Of course it is good to make a concise working example, but cutting away the entire context is not good)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number $X$ of balls in scoring positions follows a [hypergeometric
distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). There are 20 scoring positions; 340 non-scoring positions.

In R, we can make a PDF table of the distribution (rounded to five places) as shown below.
(You can ignore row numbers in brackets `[ ]`.)

```
x = 0:3;  pdf = round(dhyper(x, 20,340, 3), 5)
cbind(x, pdf)
     x     pdf
[1,] 0 0.84201
[2,] 1 0.14947
[3,] 2 0.00838
[4,] 3 0.00015
```

Here is the computation for $P(X = 2)$ in terms of binomial coefficients:

$$P(X = 2) = \frac{{20\choose 2}{340\choose 1}}{{360\choose 3}}
= 0.008377.$$

```
choose(20, 2)*choose(340, 1)/choose(360,3)
[1] 0.008377295
(190*340)/7711320
[1] 0.008377295
```